# Post request ajax with react using laravel in backend

Tags: ajax, laravel, reactjs

i want to submit very simple form using react in front end and laravel backend i use tutorial facebook react but using ES6 console log display to me  "parsererror" "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

so In React

```
handleSubmit(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var name = this.refs.name.value.trim();
    var description = this.refs.description.value.trim();

    console.log(`Name : ${name} , and  Description ${description}`);

    if (!name || !description) {
        return;
    }

    this.props.onCommentSubmit({name: name, description: description});

    this.refs.name.value = '';
    this.refs.description.value = '';
    return;
}

render(){
    return(
        <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="name" />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." ref="description" />
            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </form>
    );

}
```

and i import this class to global class

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: [] };
 }
handleCommentSubmit(d) {

    var comments = this.state.data;
    var newComments = comments.concat([d]);
    this.setState({data: newComments});


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/photo',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: d,
        context: this,
        success: (data) => {
            this.setState({data: data});
        },
        error: (xhr, status, error) => {
            console.error(this.props.url, status, error.toString());
        }
    });


}


render(){

    return(
        <FormCtl  onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit.bind(this)}/>
    );
}
```

in Backend using Laravel 5.1

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
    $photo = new Photo();

    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $data = Input::all();
        print_r($data);die;

    }

}
```

in console log i look this "parsererror" "SyntaxError: Unexpected token A"
i can't recovered data or save it in database

Comment: `dataType: 'json'` expects the server to return valid JSON. because you're printing the string/array it throws that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An simple solution would be to not print your data with print_r() but simpaly use the response json function from laravel.

```
 $data = Input::all();
 return response()->json($data);
```

Wich will return json like you request in your $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

use Fetch or Axios API instead of $ajax();

> 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', // Simulates AJAX request

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/photo', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', // Simulates AJAX request
    // Add any other headers required by your API
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(d),
})
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Handle the response data
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({ data: data });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle any errors
    console.error(error);
  });
```